# C# reportviewer group footer totals

Tags: c#, winforms, grouping, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a rdlc report that calculates revenue made by two vehicle fleets.
The report is grouped by fleet with a group footer to calculate subtotals for each fleet. 
The subtotal for fleet one gets calculated correctly but the subtotal for fleet two displays the grand total for both fleets instead of only the subtotal for fleet two.

Expression used to calculate the subtotal:

```
=Switch(
Fields!RatePer.Value = "Ton", RunningValue(Fields!rate.Value * Fields!tonnage.Value,SUM,"DataSet1"),
Fields!RatePer.Value = "Load", RunningValue(Fields!rate.Value,SUM,"DataSet1"))
```

[image: Revenue column with subtotals in grey per fleet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to reset subtotal for every fleet you need to specify your flee group name as `scope` in [RunningValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255229.aspx) function.

```
=Switch(
    Fields!RatePer.Value = "Ton",
        RunningValue(Fields!rate.Value * Fields!tonnage.Value, SUM, "fleeGroupName"),
    Fields!RatePer.Value = "Load",
        RunningValue(Fields!rate.Value, SUM, "fleeGroupName")
)
```

If I understand correctly I think you can also use a simpler expression without `RunningValue`:

```
=Switch(
    Fields!RatePer.Value = "Ton", Fields!rate.Value * Fields!tonnage.Value,
    Fields!RatePer.Value = "Load", Fields!rate.Value
)
```